# Math notation for histogram selection process

Tags: notation

Suppose you have values and classify them in a histogram. In pseudo code this may look like this:

```
foreach value
  foreach bucket
    if(value > bucket.lowerBound && value <= bucket.upperBound)
      bucket.count = bucket.count + 1
```

Is there a mathematical notation for this selection task?

Suppose $i$ is an index denoting the bucket and $j$ an index of the values. Does a nice compact notation exist for writing the count $c_i$ in bucket $i$ as a function of the lower $l_i$ and upper $u_i$ bounds of bucket $i$, akin to

$ c_i = ... someNotation (v_j, l_i, u_i)$

Or maybe a matrix notation could better fit? With $C$ the vector of counts, $V$ the vector of values and $U$,$L$ the vectors of bounds.

$C = ...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicator function is defined as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{1}_A(x) :=\begin{cases} 
1 &\text{if } x \in A, \\
0 &\text{if } x \notin A.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
So you could rewrite your expression as
\begin{align}
c_i = \sum_{j} {1}_{[l_i,r_i]}(x_j)
\end{align}
But I don't know, whether there is a matrix notation.

Edit: It might be a problem that you check for  $\quad left < x \leq right$ and not  $ left \leq x \leq right$

Comment: Thanks for that. About your edit, I need to avoid duplicate counting so need to have strict inequality on one side: left<x≤right

Comment: Ah okay, you could write it as $1_{(l_i,r_i]}$ but this does not really change the fact that you have no matrix representation.